# How to Have $HOME in Matlab's save/saveas?

Tags: matlab, save

I have distributed my computing to many platforms so I cannot use fullpath but instead relative like `$HOME`. 
Code

```
filename=strcat('$HOME/Images/',num2str(item);
save(strcat(filename,'.mat'),'masi');
saveas(her, strcat(filename,'.png'));
```

Output

```
Error using save
Cannot create '777.mat' because '$HOME/Images' does not exist.

Error in masiCool (line 98)
    save(strcat(filename,'.mat'),'masi');
```

Backward flash `\$HOME` does not work neither.

---

How can you have $HOME in Matlab's save/saveas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variables (such as `$HOME`) are not automatically parsed by MATLAB. In general, if you need the value of an environment variable, you can use [`getenv`.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getenv.html)

```
homedir = getenv('HOME');
```

Alternately, on *nix, you *can* actually just use the tilde (`~`) to represent the user's home directory in a filepath.

```
folder = '~/Images';
```

However, I typically just rely upon the [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) to get the user home directory for me since it will work properly on any platform.

```
homedir = char(java.lang.System.getProperty('user.home'));
```

Then, use [`fullfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html?refresh=true) to concatenate the path you want onto the user's home directory.

```
filename = fullfile(homedir, 'Images', sprintf('%d.mat', item))
```

> NOTE: If you are wanting to do this on an HPC or some instance of MATLAB that is not using the JVM. The `getenv` option is best. On Windows, you would want the `HOMEPATH` variable rather than `HOME`.

Comment: @Masi I think it's personal preference, but I like it because it allows be to do something like `sprintf('%d.%d.%d.mat', 1,2,3)` rather than `[num2str(1), num2str(2), num2str(3), '.mat']`

Answer (score -2):

Try full path instead of using $HOME. $HOME is a system command and it is not recognizable in Matlab.

Use  \home\YOUR_USER_NAME instead of $HOME.

TIP: In case you have to use a system command inside Matlab, [system()](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html) is a useful function.

Comment: The point is not use full path. I have distributed computing to many computers so I cannot use full path.