# How to Use fullfile in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am studying Suever's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35891081/54964) where I do not understand its application with `fullfile` in Code 1.

Code 1

```
filename=strcat('/Users/masi/Images/', 'p.1');
save(fullfile(filename,'.mat'),'time');
saveas(her, fullfile(filename,'.png'));
```

Output

```
Error using save
Cannot create '.mat' because '/Users/masi/Images/p.1' does not
exist.
```

Code 2

```
filename=strcat('/Users/masi/Images/', 'p.1');
save(strcat(filename,'.mat'),'time');
saveas(her, strcat(filename,'.png'));
```

Success!

### Change made based on Daniel's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35892907/54964)

```
filenameMat=fullfile('/Users/masi/Images/', 'p.1', '.mat');
save(filenameMat,'time');
```

but still getting

```
Error using save
Cannot create '.mat' because '/Users/masi/Images/p.1.mat' does not
exist.
```

I do not understand.

---

Why is code 1 giving the error?

Comment: Please reduce code example to the minimal required length for your question. `filename=C:\example;time=1;save(fullfile(filename,'.mat'),'time');` vs `save(strcat(filename,'.mat'),'time');` would be sufficient

Comment: @Daniel Thank you for notice! Now simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `fullfile` for a wrong application. The documentation clearly explains the parameters:

> Folder and file names, specified as strings and cell arrays of strings.

You input  a filename without extension and a file extension, hat is not what fullfile is made for. It will insert a file separator between both:

```
>> fullfile('foo','.bar')

ans =

foo\.bar
```

`fullfile` would be the right function to construct `filename`.

Comment: I extended the body where I do not understand one thing.

Comment: `'.mat'` is not a file or folder name, it is not a input argument for fullfile

Comment: It would be nice to understand what is the thinking that .mat file is not about a file. Limiting a file to a small subset does not make sense.

Comment: Fullfile is "thinking" `.mat` is the full filename, not only an extension.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent such a behaviour in fullfile?

Comment: No, use street to concatenate filename and extension, then use fullfile. I typically write `fullfile(l1,l2,l3,[name,ext])` with l1...l3 being the folders and name, ext being the file